# Friend template overloaded operator <<: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

I'm having issues with the error

> Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl cop4530::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class rob::Stack const &)" (??6rob@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV12@ABV?$Stack@H@0@@Z) referenced in function _main    Project7    c:\Users\Robrik\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project7\Project7\post.obj    1

Right now, all that `post` is doing is calling the `operator<<`

The declaration

```
namespace rob {     

template < typename T> class Stack {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a);
    void print(std::ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const;
private:
    std::vector<T> arr;
};
```

The definition

```
template < typename T>
inline std::ostream & rob::operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Stack<T>& a)                {     
    return a.print(os, ' ');
}
template<typename T>
inline void rob::Stack<T>::print(std::ostream & os, char c) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i != arr.size(); i++)
    {
        os << c << arr[i];
    }
    os << '\n';
}
```

They are located in a `.h` file and a `.hpp` respectively, I require that the operator is not a member function (for assignment).

Comment: Possibly the hpp file is not included by whatever file is using the `operator<<`. To get a better answer, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Obviously you did not post your real code (e.g. your `Stack` as shown does not have any member `arr`) so you are really asking us to guess what mistake you might have made in your real code.

Comment: also check [template friends FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends) in case your problem is covered there

Comment: the files are included together properly, as other functions declared in the .h file and defined in the .hpp file work. It's only the operator overloads which are having linker issues, which, I'm sure if I can fix one, the others will be fixed the same way.

Comment: I know you have solved this problem, but see my answer to the reason for the error to begin with and the possible alternatives you have.

Comment: I couldn't find a decent duplicate of this (especially relating to the unresolved symbol), so +1 for asking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should as well declare function signature inside rob namespace which it actually belongs:

```
namespace rob {
template <typename T>
class Stack {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a);
};

template < typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a){
    ...
}
```

Comment: That didn't fix the issue, but regardless, they are supposed to be located in different files (.h for declaration, and hpp for definition).

Comment: @Robert Hook Function header and function implementation is still in different files. "Friend" signature is just a permission to this function to access private or protected members/methods. With this access should exists an function itself which can be defined as pair: signature in header and implementation in cpp file.

Comment: @Robert BTW, both inline and template will not work outside class. You should emplace this kind of function in header.

Comment: I got it to work with  template <T> friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a); on h and 
template<typename T>
std::ostream& rob::operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a) on hpp. Thanks! the template <T> had me over the coals for a while.

Answer (score 11):

The issue with the code sample;

```
template <typename T>
class Stack {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a);
    void print(std::ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const;
    // ...
};
```

Is that the `operator<<` is being declared as a non-template function. For every type `T` used with `Stack`, there needs to be a non-template `operator<<`. For example, if there is a type `Stack<int>` declared, then there must be an operator implementation as follows;

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<int>& a) {/*...*/}
```

Since it is not implemented, the linker fails to find it and results in the error you get.

*As a side note; gcc warns about this as follows*

> `warning: friend declaration 'std::ostream& operator<<(...)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]`
>
> `note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)`

This is probably not what is intended, that every instantiation has its own implementation.

To correct this, you can declare a template operator before the `Stack` type and then declare as a friend, an instantiation. The syntax looks a little awkward, but is looks as follows;

```
// forward declare the Stack
template <typename>
class Stack;

// forward declare the operator <<
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Stack<T>&);

template <typename T>
class Stack {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a);
    // note the required <>        ^^^^
    void print(std::ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const;
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Stack<T>&)
{
  // ... implement the operator
}
```

The above code limits the friendship of the operator to the corresponding instantiation of `Stack`, i.e. the `operator<< <int>` instantiation is limited to access the private members of the instantiation of `Stack<int>`.

Alternatives include allowing the friendship to extend to all instantiations of the templates;

```
template <typename T>
class Stack {
    template <typename T1>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stack<T1>& a);
    // ...
};
```

The implementation for the `operator<<` could then be done inline inside the class definition, or outside.

Comment: Most obscure code for me, especial the 'operator<< <>(...)' part. Tested all variations and it works fine and that is what counts. Still I would like to *understand* the why and how. Well one day I might.

Comment: For an example by Stroustrup for 'operator<< <>(...)' see the C++ prog lang. ISBN9780321563842, chapter 'Templates', par. 23.4.7 Friends on page 682.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @LibertyPaul's answer you need to add a `template<T>` to friend `std::os...` line, in order to work:

```
namespace rob {

   template <typename T> class Stack {
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a) {
              return a.arr.print(os, ' ');
        }
   };

}
```

Comment: This worked getting the linker error, but now there is a C2248 error, saying the function can't access private member data. Using @LibertyPaul's answer.

Comment: @RobertHook is the template that cause this problem. Without the template it can access Stack's private members

Comment: The only way to make it work is to write the definition of ostream operator inside the class. I edit my answer

Comment: I got it to work with template <T> friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a); on h and                                                                   template<typename T> std::ostream& rob::operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a)                                                               on hpp. Thanks! the template <T> had me over the coals for a while.